# AngularJS: ng-model does not update when ng-options refreshes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, so I apologize if this question is naive.

We have cascading selects that populate as you select values. When the value of Select A changes, the values in Select B also change since they filter based on the value in Select A.

So here is the scenario:

1. Choose option from Select A
2. Choose option from Select B
3. Change selection for Select A
4. Observe that options in Select B update accordingly.
5. Observe that bound model for Select B does not update accordingly.

This seems so basic that we are really scratching our heads.  What is the point of two-way data binding if this scenario isn't covered?

Here is my view:

```
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   Make:
    <select ng-model="makeng" ng-options="option.value as option.display for option in makes">
        <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a make</option>
    </select>
  <br /> 
  {{makeng}}

  <br /> <br /> 

  Model:
    <select ng-model="modelng" ng-options="option.display for option in models | filter:{make:makeng}">
        <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a model</option>
    </select>
    {{modelng}}
  </body>
```

Here's a Plunkr, demonstrating:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9XrKgW?p=preview

P.S. The above example is purely fictional and forked from another plunkr. Just the easiest way to demonstrate what we are seeing.

Comment: That plunker is working for me. What are you expecting to happen? In that plunker, the data isn't hooked up to anything, you need to add some ng-change functions on those if you want things to happen.

Comment: Try selecting Toyota, then Tacoma.  Then select Chevrolet and notice that  the model value is still Tacoma.  It should clear as there isn't a valid selection. Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/081B0l1e1G0h

Comment: Thats what your data says. That model thats being displayed is coming from the ng-model on the model select. If you want it to actually do something, you have to put an ng-change on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to work. The `select` control changes the model in response to a user's selection, but if you change the set of allowed values from underneath it (i.e. by filtering out) it keeps the model intact.

The way to make this work is by invalidating the model in response to a change in `Select A`:

```
Make:
<select ng-model="makeng" 
      ng-options="option.value as option.display for option in makes"
      ng-change="modelng = undefined">
   <option value="">Select a make</option>
</select>
<br /> 

Model:
<select ng-model="modelng" 
        ng-options="option.display for option in models | filter:{make:makeng}">
   <option value="">Select a model</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is essentially the solution we came up with, but as the complexity increases we are having to invalidate multiple models per dropdown in some instances, which feels heavy and wrong.  I'll leave this open in case someone else chimes in with a more elegant solution, but if not I'll give you credit :)

Comment: @clifgriffin, this is really "by design" - the input controls do not inadvertently change the model without the controller knowing about it (this would make unit-testing of controllers impossible if `prop1` could be invalidated indirectly by changing `prop2` - this case would be entirely missed by unit testing). So, really, this is the only way.